# How to show a hidden div on-drag of HTML div to another location

Tags: javascript

I have a Code and OnDrag of it i need to show a div and on drop i want to Hide it. I am using dragula drag and drop script which is working fine. But after using the toggle or javascript show it's not working at all.

Below is my javascript

```
dragula([$('leadin'), $('contactmade'), $('prospectqualified'),  $('needdefined'),$('proposalmade'),$('negotiationstarted')])

  .on('drag', function (el) {
    el.className = el.className.replace('ex-moved', '');


    // Want to show a Div
    document.getElementById('dealownstatus').ondrag=function(){

      document.getElementById('element').style.display='block';
    };



  })
  .on('drop', function (el) {
    el.className += ' ex-moved';
  })
  .on('over', function (el, container) {
    container.className += ' ex-over';
  })
  .on('out', function (el, container) {
    container.className = container.className.replace('ex-over', '');
});
```

Any Suggestion ?

*This is the Dragula Github https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: This is the URL http://webapplications.co.in/nextstepcrm/deal.html, On drag and drop I want the below div with three button will be visible. But after putting any code under the   .on('drag', function (el) {} the whole drag and drop is not working. I have tried with this below code

document.getElementById('dealownstatus').ondrag=function(){

      document.getElementById('element').style.display='block';
    };

Answer (score 0):

You can use without ondrag=function()

```
dragula([$('leadin'), $('contactmade'), $('prospectqualified'),  $('needdefined'),$('proposalmade'),$('negotiationstarted')])
  .on('drag', function (el) {
    el.className = el.className.replace('ex-moved', '');
        document.getElementById('element').style.display='block';
     })
  .on('drop', function (el) {
    el.className += ' ex-moved';
    document.getElementById('element').style.display='none';
  })
  .on('over', function (el, container) {
    container.className += ' ex-over';
  })
  .on('out', function (el, container) {
    container.className = container.className.replace('ex-over', '');
});
```